# Grammacally Correct or not

Tags: grammar, email

'If you still have any concern feel free to ask them'

Is this sentence is correct or not? If it is wrong, can you please provide better suggestion

Comment: "Any" is normally followed by a plural if you're referring to countable objects (concerns would be countable, usually). https://dictionary.cambridge.org/grammar/british-grammar/any

Comment: It is fine, except that 'concern' should have a comma after it.

Answer (score 1):

As a complete sentence I think this could be clearer on who or what is referred to as "them".

If them is a person, then perhaps that is indicated in the previous sentence - we'd need to see that to understand it.

I suspect you may be using "them" to refer to the concerns, which feels a little stilted;  I would expect to *raise* concerns (and ask questions).
i.e. "If you still have any concerns feel free to raise them"

Comment: Hello, dichohecho. A fine answer (though you choose not to correct the concern/concerns issue; I assume you're not wanting to appear over-punctilious). But the question is poorly stated and doesn't really belong on ELU. / As a comment points out, 'concerns' would be standard here; a question suitable for ELU would be whether 'If you still have any concern' ['ask' obviously needs replacing], using a non-count usage, is acceptable. And then whether 'concern' rather than 'a concern' or 'concerns' may be 'raised'.